# Jar file won't run - Windows 7

Tags: netbeans, jar, java

I am trying to run a .jar file that I have created using either the command line and double clicking.  The Jar makes a `JFrame` GUI with button, text, labels etc.. It should display this window.

I have checked and the file is associated with javaw.exe in the correct directly. I have also tried via the command like using `java -jar filename.jar` and it just paused for a split second and then moves to the next line, no errors.

I have also run javafix which also hasn't helped.

I have reinstalled JRE and JKE and still no luck, the file was created in Netbeans and compiles without problem.

I am using this Netbeans tutorial: [Introduction to GUI Building](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html).

Any suggestions? I'm Stumped.

Comment: Just for the sake of confirmation, does the jar have a manifest entry for main-class? Could you try the conventional java -cp filename.jar your.main.class-name (without the .class prefix to classname) also?

Comment: *"it just paused for a split second and then moves to the next line, no errors."*  FTR - What did you **expect** to see?  Does the Jar produce a GUI?  Does it process a file and send output to `System.out` or `System.err`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, Sorry I should have mentioned. It uses a Jframe Gui with Button, Text, Labels etc.. It should display this window.

Comment: @d-live Sorry, this is my first attempt at java coming from c#. Im not really sure what you are asking. I have added a link to the tutorial I am working from if that helps.

Comment: Do other Jar files run?  E.G.  Here is a small (32Kb) app. of mine with a GUI, [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/#download).  What happens when you try to run that from the command line?

Comment: ok, does it run from within the netbeans? Exercise 4: Running the Program, To run the program in the IDE, Step 1?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That runs fine. It must be something I doing wrong in Netbeans. d-live: It compiles succsesfully in Netbeans, but doens't disaply the Gui. Its odd as I followed the tutorial word for word.

Comment: *"It compiles succsesfully in Netbeans, but doens't disaply the Gui"* If it does not display the GUI when run in Netbeans, it will not work as a Jar!  Sort that out first.

Comment: @d-live You were right. I made the mistake of having a main class that wasn't required. I should have used the jframe package as my main class. This fixed the issue. If you put this as the answer I will tick. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @Rhys, Glad to hear that you were able to sort it out. I'll write that as an answer if you can accept it :) And wish you a very Happy new Year, Cheers!

Comment: @d-live No Problem, just waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can tell is to Press Win + R and type regedit.exe, Press Enter.

In your Registry Editor Window, Expand `HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Software->Microsoft->Windows->CurrentVersion->Explorer->FileExts`

Delete the entry or Key Name .jar from the list. Do check the version used by your NetBeans and the one on your classpath. Hopefully they both are same versions, it can be one of the reasons too, for .jar not working. Now again try to run your .jar file. That might help it to run again.

Regards